# Android HTTPUrlConnection GetResponseCode enters endless loop

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I'm using HTTPUrlConnection to connect to a proxy server, and using the wrong proxy credentials. When I call getResponseCode I expect to receive 401- authentication failed. However instead getResponseCode enters an endless loop, and keeps sending the (failed) request to the server again and again.

If the same wrong credentials were entered through the browser, there would be a popup screen that would pop up to request the credential again.

I tried setting keepAlive to false, and I tried setting the credentials in a Cookie. Neither of these solutions helped.

Here is the code:

```
           connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           if(connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection){
                ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
            }

              connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(sUrl[0]));

                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "User name = "+ this.User + "; Password = " + this.Password);


            connection.connect();

            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            int HTTPResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: In case it was being caused by a server bug which is sending endless redirects, I also tried setting: connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); but this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Set timeout.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(10000); // set in milliseconds
connection.setReadTimeout(10000); // set in milliseconds
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this solution and it didn't help. I'm trying to understand why getResponseCode is entering an endless loop in the first place?